# What is the purpose of CGContextSaveGState and CGContextRestoreGState?

Tags: core-graphics

I see a lot of sample code where they use `CGContextSaveGState` and `CGContextRestoreGState`.  Why would I need to save the state of the context?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to restore it later.

Some of the things you can change about a context are difficult (e.g., CTM) or impossible (e.g., clipping path) to change back. Saving the gstate lets you undo those changes by restoring the gstate.

[The Quartz 2D Programming Guide tells all.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-TPXREF132)

Comment: Ohhhh, it's the STATE that's being restored and not the entire drawing. That clears everything up. (I.e., something I draw will stay, but my changes to CTM will revert.)

Comment: @Colas: Current transformation matrix—the part of the graphics state you're changing when you translate, scale, rotate, or skew.

Comment: @Colas When you call any Core Graphics methods with CTM in them, like CGContextTranslateCTM or CGContextScaleCTM, the CTM is what keeps track of all those changes and applies it to the context you pass in.  It's like the directions for rotations/scaling/etc. If you don't want to apply each transformation one at a time like that,  you can group a bunch up and apply them at once to the CTM also -> [Creating Affine Transforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-CJBHFCIB)